# How do I control the formatting style of JSON in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

There is apparently built in support in VS Code to format JSON files. However, I do not see a way to customize the way the formatting is done (e.g. specifying line breaks before curly-braces, brackets, etc). I have also [read some documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_formatting) related to this but it doesn't go into any detail. Is there a way to customize how the formatting works in Visual Studio Code for JSON files?

Comment: Ref page is here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default formatter of JSON have only few features, like changing tab size.

Open Preferences with File > Preferences > Settings (Ctrl + ,) > User Settings (or Workspace Settings) tab > [JSON] "Edit in settings.json" link

or

Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) > Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings > JSON

and add language specific settings.

Refs: [Creating User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings) [Language specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)

**settings.json** (sample)

```
{
    "[json]": {
        // JSON specific settings goes here
        // "editor.tabSize": 4
    }
}
```

For further customization, use extensions found in market place.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more json formatting option in Insiders v1.70 now.

```
JSON > Format: Keep Lines
Keep all existing new lines when formatting.
```

That is disabled by default.  Enabling it will keep any empty lines in json documents when formatting AND keep multiple entries on the same line as in the original - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180702/836330 for an example.

```json
{
    "big_integer_array": [12,15,13,1,5,8,15,14,12],
    "this_value_is_in_line_three": true
}
```

will stay that way and not drop down like

```json
{
    "big_integer_array": [
        12,
        15,
        13,
        1,
        5,
        8,
        15,
        14,
        ...
      ]
}
```

like it will with the setting disabled.  Also multiple key/value pairs can appear on the same line now.

Comment: Thanks.  Sadly, this doesn't affect how VSCode formats its own files like tasks.json, probably because it recreates them from scratch each time.