# How can I configure VS Code to format JSON with new-lines before opening braces/brackets?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Reading multi-line blocks with opening braces/brackets at the end of a line is utterly hard for me to read.

I'm pretty much used to read B-style code having multi-line blocks starting on a new line, so I can easily match opening to closing braces/brackets, e.g.:

```json
{
  "aaa" :
  {
    "bbb" :
    [
      1,
      2,
    ]
  },
  "ccc": "x"
}
```

I can't find a setting in VS Code to set that kind of formatting when <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is pressed.

Is there a way to manually edit the `settings.json` file accordingly?

Comment: if you can't find a JSON formatter that does what you want write one yourself, it is not that hard

Comment: there are 7 settings related to JSON and none is about configuring the options of the formatter, maybe an other JSON extension does what you want

Comment: related: [What JSON formatter does Visual Studio Code use to format JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76056894/11107541)

Comment: Is it already formatted like you want (and want to prevent any change on formatting) or do you want to reformat an existing json file to end up with your example?  If the first, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028842/836330.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Mark, it's the second option. Tools generate `JSON` files all the time and re-format them. After that, I want to have them re-formatted "my way", so I can easily read them.

Comment: I went through several extensions, but they all don't seem to provide such formatting.